# Is it possible to remove the title bar from an msi installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have one .msi file (created with WiX) that creates one customized UI. I want to remove the title bar that comes by default. Is it possible to do that?

I have written the code in XML.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to customize the control bar.

You can bundle your MSI with a WiX Bootstrapper and create the UI you need.